# Display streaming video and result of a python code at the same time in a web-browser

Tags: python, django

I need to display a streaming video and also the output of a python code running simultaneously. What is the best framework to go about designing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually sending the video, or are you sending an HTML page with an embedded video (either with Flash or HTML5)? If the former, showing other output would be impossible. If the latter, you can have it anywhere else on the page.

Comment: I will be sending an HTML page with an embedded video using Flash.

Comment: Will the output of the code be streaming in real time alongside the video?

Comment: You could have javascript asynchronously pull data from the python program (assuming it is running as a webserver) and update the page with it.